# given - when statement doesn't work properly ('Learning Perl' Chapter 15 issue)

Tags: perl

The example of using the given-when statement presented in chapter 15 of the  "Learning Perl" book does not work properly.
I'm using Perl v5.22.1. and I tried to reproduce the following code (see "Learning Perl", fifth edition, page 227.):

```
    use 5.010;
    given ($ARGV[0])
    {
       when(/fred/i) {say "Name has fred in it"; continue}
       when(/^Fred/) {say "Name starts with Fred"; continue}
       when('Fred')  {say "Name is Fred";}
       default {say "I don't see a Fred"}
    }
```

When I run the script, I get the following result:

```
D:\>Perl D:\Perl\Example113.pl Frederick
given is experimental at D:\Perl\Example113.pl line 5.
when is experimental at D:\Perl\Example113.pl line 7.
when is experimental at D:\Perl\Example113.pl line 8.
when is experimental at D:\Perl\Example113.pl line 9.
Name has fred in it
Name starts with Fred
I don't see a Fred
```

As you can see, the default block works contrary to expectations.
At the same time if you swap first and last blocks 'when', it is works almost as described in the book:

```
    use 5.010;
    given ($ARGV[0])
    {
       when('Fred')  {say "Name is Fred"; continue}
       when(/^Fred/) {say "Name starts with Fred"; continue}
       when(/fred/i) {say "Name has fred in it"; }
       default {say "I don't see a Fred"}
    }
```

What gives us the next output:

```
D:\>Perl D:\Perl\Example113.pl Frederick
given is experimental at D:\Perl\Example113.pl line 5.
when is experimental at D:\Perl\Example113.pl line 7.
when is experimental at D:\Perl\Example113.pl line 8.
when is experimental at D:\Perl\Example113.pl line 9.
Name starts with Fred
Name has fred in it
```

Am I doing something wrong or in the book is an incorrect example?

Comment: The diagnostic output mentions "line 5". What's in the other lines in your script?

Comment: Yes, I omitted a few lines, such as:   `#!/usr/bin/perl`
  `use strict;`
  `use warnings;`

Comment: I've got the 4th and the 6th edition here. There is no significant difference in the 6th edition. The `/^Fred/` has `/\AFred/`, and it's `use 5.010001`.

Comment: So you also tend to think that given example is incorrect?

Comment: I get the same behavior, which is correct; the `'Fred'` needs an exact string (true for `'Fred'` not for `'Frede'`), it's not a regex match.  Is that the question?

Comment: Can you please explain why the default block is runs?

Comment: @PeterV. If you are asking me -- because `'Fred'` is not `Frederick` (while `/Fred/` would be a regex so it would _match_ it) so it falls through

Comment: @zdim I think I understood, - it's because the default block is really a when a condition which is always true.

Comment: Learning Perl 5th edition was written for Perl 5.10. `given`/`when` has changed a lot since then. 7th edition covers up to Perl 5.24.

Comment: @Quentin, That's not true. Not only does the OP's program produce the same output in 5.10.1 and 5.26.0 (except for the experimental warnings), I'm pretty sure the only changes to `given`/`when` since 5.10.1 is the addition of experimental warnings, and that `given` now localizes and sets the global $_ instead of creating and setting a lexical $_ (since lexical $_ no longer exists).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `continue`, `when` and `default` exit the surrounding `given` or move to the next item of the surrounding `for`.

With `continue`, execution proceeds with the next statement.

The `default` block is unconditionally executed when reached.

---

For example,

```
given ($ARGV[0]) {
    say "Checking for 'x'";
    when (/x/) { say 'contains an x'; continue; }
    say "Checking for 'y'";
    when (/y/) { say 'contains a y';            }
    default    { say 'does not contain a y';    }
}
```

For `y`:

```
Checking for 'x'
Checking for 'y'
contains a y
```

For `x`:

```
Checking for 'x'
contains an x
Checking for 'y'
does not contain a y
```

For `xy`:

```
Checking for 'x'
contains an x
Checking for 'y'
contains a y
```

Answer (score 5):

First, while exploration and play is good I must repeat what [perlsyn says](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Experimental-Details-on-given-and-when)

> As previously mentioned, the "switch" feature is considered highly
>     experimental; it is subject to change with little notice.

If that isn't enough, here is a bit more, earlier [in perlsyn](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Switch-Statements)

> Exactly what the *EXPR* argument to `when` does is hard to describe
>       precisely, but in general, it tries to guess what you want done. Sometimes
>       it is interpreted as `$_ ~~ EXPR`, and sometimes it does not. It also
>       behaves differently when lexically enclosed by a `given` block than it
>       does when dynamically enclosed by a `foreach` loop. The rules are far too
>       difficult to understand to be described here. See [Experimental Details on
>       given and when](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Experimental-Details-on-given-and-when) later on.

I don't know what to think about a feature which "*is hard to describe precisely*." Also note that "*Most of the power comes from the implicit smartmatching*" (same page). What matters is that it seems crystal clear that this *will* change, and very likely significantly.

Having cleared that up, the behavior you show is expected. From the [example in perlsyn](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Experimental-Details-on-given-and-when)

> ```
> given ($foo) {
>     when (undef) {
>         say '$foo is undefined';
>     }
>     when ("foo") {
>        say '$foo is the string "foo"';
>     }
>     ...
> }
> ```

where `$foo` need be *equal to* the string `"foo"`, not matched by it; this isn't a regex match but string equality.

In  your examples the *string* `'Fred'` *is not equal* to `Frederick`. In the second one there is that `continue` so it does go to the next branch, but in the first one there isn't (while it's also last before `default`). Run the program with input `Fred` to see.